# Visual Studio Web Performance Test

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2010, testing, web

I'm running into a "bad request" error when playing back a test.  I've tracked it down to a comma and space in a button that has "Yes, Do" as its value.  There is functionality in another page that runs based on this value.  When I remove the comma and space in the both pages everything works perfectly.  I've tried toggling the 'url encode' property for that field in the Web Perf Test to true, but it still fails.  When I look at the details of the request it shows "Yes,+Do" as the querystring param.  I can't change the control value in this situation.  Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems odd that the value of a button is being passed as a query string parameter in the first place...

Is it set up where there is an extraction rule from a prior request and then that context parameter is used for a later request?  If so, you can actually modify the value.  You can either hard code the value in the later request, or if you still need to get it dynamically but just modify it, you can create a pretty simple plugin.  Sample code for it would be:

```
public class StringCharsFromParam: WebTestRequestPlugin
{
    public override void PreRequest(object sender, PreRequestEventArgs e)
    {
        string ExtractParam =  ((string)e.WebTest.Context["NameOfContextParameter"]);
        if (ExtractParam != null && ExtractParam.Contains(", ")
        {
            e.WebTest.Context["NameOfContextParameter"] = ExtractParam.Replace(", ", "");
        }
    }
}
```

You would then add this WebTestRequestPlugin to your WebTest.

Comment: I agree about button value.

I tried your suggestion, but I'm unable to extract and replace the querystring param before it's sent out.  I've tried creating a custom Extraction rule, the WebTestRequestPlugin you suggested, and even tried making some alterations by way of 

[code]
QueryStringParameter queryStringParamter =  new QueryStringParameter("myAction","Yes, Do");
            e.Request.QueryStringParameters.Add(queryStringParamter);
[/code]

Everything looks good when I step through, but it still ends up munged.  Trying to figure out how to catch the request right before it is sent.